# chartjs display data in one bar line with 3 different data sets in 3 different colors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I currently display my data like this:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bebx.png)

but I would like to display the data like this:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsFjz.png)

The idea is that at the bottom it would show the summary of all three colors numbers combined, but once you hover it would show how much each color has.

If all is one bar, if red is 7, blue is 3, the red but be a lot more in the bar.

This is the code for version 1, done with chart js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Blue",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [3, 7, 4]
        },
        {
            label: "Red",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            data: [4, 3, 5]
        },
        {
            label: "Green",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            data: [7, 2, 6]
        }
    ]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        barValueSpacing: 20,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is the next, you are using a wrong config you must something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="MyChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("MyChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [2017],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Chocolate",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#eece01",
      data: [30],
    }, {
      label: "Vanilla",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#87d84d",
      data: [-15],
    }, {
      label: "Strawberry",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#f8981f",      
      data: [20],
    }, {
      label: "candy",
      type: "bar",
      stack: "Base",
      backgroundColor: "#00b300",
      backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
      data: [-10]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Now you just need to fix the styles and sizes of the graphic

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds this, the solution is this:

```
  const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: data,
      options: {
        plugins: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
          },
          y: {
            stacked: true
          }
        }
      }
};
```